# check my c++ code! My cmd screen is closing after running it! What could be my error?

Tags: c++

I can't detect the error in the following code:

```
int add(int x[], int size, int y[]=0) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += x[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += y[i];
}
return sum;
}

int main() {

   int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
   int b[] = { 6,7,8,9,10 };
   int c = add(a, 5);
   int d = add(a, 5, b);
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just because the command prompt closes doesn't mean anything is broken.

Comment: Why would you expect it to do anything else? After `cout << d << endl;`, your code is finished, and the application exits. It's working exactly as you've written it, and nothing is broken at all.

Comment: You really shouldn't use so many exclamation marks. We would help you anyway, you know. (Or we wouldn't, but the exclamation marks won't change that)

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal, as far as I understand.
The program is executed, and once finished it's closed.
If you want to see the results execute the program from an existing CMD.

```
C:/location> program.exe
```

Comment: oh sorry! I didn't mean that! I meant after running the code...cmd stops working!

Comment: What do you mean stop working? Getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running without debugging? Try hitting ctrl + f5 if you're in visual studio and the command should stay opened when your code finishes.